# Roslyn to ignore subtrees

Tags: c#, syntax, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to use Roslyn and implement my own node visitors by extending `CSharpSyntaxWalker` and overriding its `Visit...` methods. But I have a problem.

Consider the following C# class:

```
class MyClass {
  private void DoSomething() { ... }
  public void DoSomethingElse() { ... }
  public class MyClass2 {
    private int GetSomething() { ... }
  }
}
```

I need to react only to methods defined in `MyClass`. I can get a reference to that node. So I can get a reference to a `SyntaxNode` representing `MyClass`, so that I can do:

```
CSharpSyntaxWalker.Visit(node); // node is a SyntaxNode
```

However the visit will react to `GetSomething` method, which I want to exclude from the visit. Actually I want to exclude `MyClass2`. So, in my custom walker, I can override visit methods to react to methods, but when I encounter a class declaration i would like to instruct the visitor to ignore that node.

```
public class MyWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker {
  public override void VisitMethodDeclaration { ... }
  public override void VisitClassDeclaration {
    // Do something to exclude this node and its subtree from the visit...
  }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't call `base.Visit` for nodes you don't want to recurse into.